# SAS SQL: how to stack values of different columns into one column?

Tags: sql, sas

the data I have is,

```
id    date1    date1_flag    date2    date2_flag    date3    date3_flag
001   20020212      1         
032   20061130      1
020                          20060603      2
040   20041023      1
094                          20090110      2
044                                                 20040320       3
```

.. and on for a little over 200,000 entries

I would like to have,

```
id    date       date_flag
001   20020212      1    
032   20061130      1
020   20060603      2
040   20041023      1
094   20090110      2
044   20040320      3
```

basically I would like to just scooch all dates into one column and all date_flags into one column.

Each id has only one date (ex. an id cannot have date1 AND date2).
I thought it would be easy at first, but I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the coalesce function like this:

```
proc sql;
create table NewTable as
select coalesce(date1, date2, date3) as date
, coalesce(date1_flag, date2_flag, date3_flag) as date_flag
from YourTable;
quit;
```

Coalesce will use the first value it finds. So if you are sure you will have only one date/flag per row this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of solutions to this...

You could do it in a data step, with an array function. You could do it using `coalesce` as Oliver suggested. You could also do it using a UNION:

```
proc sql;
    select id, date1 as date, 1 as date_flag
    from YourTable
    where date1~=.

    union all
    select id, date2 as date, 2 as date_flag
    from YourTable
    where date2~=.

    union all
    select id, date3 as date, 3 as date_flag
    from YourTable
    where date3~=.
quit;
```

Or, finally, you could do it using a SQL case statement, but that's probably unnecessarily complex, so I won't get into it.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already noted that there are multiple ways of doing this. You might like to do it in `proc sql`, but I would just do it in the data step loop using conditional statements.

```
data work.Temp (rename = (date1 = date date1_flag = date_flag));
    input id date1 date1_flag date2 date2_flag date3 date3_flag;
    if date2 NE . then date1 = date2;
    if date3 NE . then date1 = date3;
    if date2_flag NE . then date1_flag = date2_flag;
    if date3_flag NE . then date1_flag = date3_flag;
    drop date2 date2_flag date3 date3_flag;

    datalines;
    001   20020212      1 . . . . 
    032   20061130      1 . . . .  
    020       .          .         20060603      2 . . 
    040   20041023      1 . . . .  
    094         .         .        20090110      2  . . 
    044         .         .            .          .         20040320       3 
    ;

run;

proc print data=work.temp; run;
```

The period `.` represents that the data value is empty/missing.